# Swift: How to remove last character

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am doing an app with eureka forms (costum rows) and the problem is that when i want to calculate firstValue with percentageField dosen't calculate correct because when i try to convert to double can't convert % in double ex: 
firstValue = 34
percentageField = 9%
Problem is that "9%" can't convert to double and the value is 0
percentageField*firstValue = 0 because cant convert %

Code :

```
func eingabessumeBruttoCalc(forPercentage isPercentage: Bool){
        let rowEingabessumeBrutto: KalkulationRow = (formViewController()?.form.rowBy(tag:"eingabessumeBrutto"))!
       let rowRabatt: KalkulationRow = (formViewController()?.form.rowBy(tag:"rabatt"))!
        let rowSkonto: KalkulationRow = (formViewController()?.form.rowBy(tag:"skonto"))!
        let rowDiverse: KalkulationRow = (formViewController()?.form.rowBy(tag:"diverse"))!
        let rowZielBrutto:KalkulationRow = (formViewController()?.form.rowBy(tag:"zielBrutto"))!
        let rowZielNetto:KalkulationRow = (formViewController()?.form.rowBy(tag:"zielNetto"))!
        let rowEingabessumeNetto:KalkulationRow = (formViewController()?.form.rowBy(tag:"result"))!

        let ValueEingabessumeBrutto = Double(rowEingabessumeBrutto.cell.valueField.text ?? "") ?? 00
        let ValueEingabessumeNetto = Double(rowEingabessumeNetto.cell.valueField.text ?? "") ?? 00


        let ValueZielBrutto = Double(rowZielBrutto.cell.percentageField.text ?? "")  ?? 00
        let totalZielBrutto = ValueEingabessumeBrutto * ValueZielBrutto * 0.01
        rowZielBrutto.cell.valueField.text = total.description

        let ValueRabatt = Double(rowRabatt.cell.percentageField.text ?? "")  ?? 00
        let totalRabatt = ValueEingabessumeBrutto * ValueRabatt * 0.01
        rowRabatt.cell.valueField.text = total.description

        let SkontoValue = Double(rowSkonto.cell.percentageField.text ?? "")  ?? 00
        let rowsSkonto = Double(rowEingabessumeBrutto)-Double(rowRabatt)
        let totalSkonto = rowSkonto * SkontoValue * 0.01
        rowSkonto.cell.valueField.text = total.description

        let ValueDiverse = Double(rowDiverse.cell.percentageField.text ?? "")  ?? 00
        let totalDierse = ValueEingabessumeBrutto * ValueDiverse * 0.01
        rowDiverse.cell.valueField.text = total.description

        let ValueZielNetto = Double(rowZielNetto.cell.percentageField.text ?? "")  ?? 00
        let totalDierse = ValueEingabessumeNetto * ValueZielNetto * 0.01
        rowZielNetto.cell.valueField.text = total.description
```

> ```
>       if let text = percentageField.text,
>             !text.isEmpty {
>             percentageField.text?.removeLast()
>
>         }
> ```
>
> This is what i try.

I want to check if the last character is % remove it.

Comment: You're repeatedly repeating yourself, which is causing a lot of repetition. You should extract the similar parts to functions. Also, the swift convention is to use lowerCamelCase for all local, instance, static and class variables. UpperCamelCase is reserved for the names of types.

Comment: @Alexander sorry i am new in swift, for this reason I ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if let text = textField.text, let lastChar = text.last, lastChar == "%" {
    textField.text = String(text.dropLast())
}
```